# Show "open application indicator" only for applications active in current desktop

Tags: macos, dock, desktop, spaces, mission-control

Short version:

As I have written in the title, I want to see the "open application indicator" only below the applications that are open in the active desktop. Is this possible?

Long version:

I had been using Windows all my life and now for about a month I have been using a Macbook. I typically use virtual desktops for different purposes and almost all of them involve the use of web browser (For example, programming stuff on desktop1, another kind of programming stuff on desktop2 :), designing stuff on desktop 3, homework on desktop 4 etc..). However, on Mac, when I have like more than 5 desktops, those indicators being under all open applications on all desktops makes me really really frustrated and confused. Combine that with mac's auto rearrangement for desktops(depending on recent use) finding the web browser window I seek takes forever. When I disable automatic rearrangement, maximizing a window puts it all the way to the last desktop which is another frustration so neither that makes it any better. It all seems really really weird to me. So is it possible to make the Mac's Dock and Spaces function like Windows 10's taskbar and Desktops? Or at least, the short version question?

(I use OSX ElCapitan)

Comment: The simplest workaround is don't use auto-arrange & don't use fullscreen. Then everything will stay where you put it. As a long-time Spaces user, I find those 2 things to be the most counter-intuitive & counter-productive… makes you guess where everything is rather than always just knowing.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, but thats only one problem. The real problem is that I see all open applications on all spaces in every space's dock. It really makes me frustrated because after about half an hour I find myself using spaces randomly rather than using one space for one purpose and then things get really messy. I wish I could just bring windows 10's taskbar and virtual desktop logic into mac